# Subdomain Doesn't Work With Actual Domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, subdomain

I have this code:

```
const app = express();

const accountApp = express();
const publicApp = express();

publicApp.use(express.static(path.join(process.cwd(), "web/dist/public")));
accountApp.use(express.static(path.join(process.cwd(), "web/dist/account")));

app.use(vhost('account.*', accountApp));
app.use(publicApp);
```

It works perfectly on `localhost`: `http://localhost:3000` shows public app, `http://account.localhost:3000` shows account app

I hosted it on heroku, added subdomain like this:
[image: heroku-domains-setup]

And this is on google domains:
[image: google-domains-setup]

And when I go to `www.stravamenu.com` it show public app, as it should. But on `account.stravamenu.com` it shows public app instead of account app.

**Is the problem in `vhost`? Or is it heroku or google domains?**

Comment: What is `vhost`?

Comment: If `account.localhost` shows account app when `localhost` shows public app, for the case when `www.stravamenu.com` shows public app one would expect the account app to be served at `account.www.stravamenu.com`!

Comment: @Bergi `vhost` is a library that helps to handle subdomains. `account.www.stravamenu.com` doesn't work either. How can I serve account app on `account.stravamenu.com`?

Comment: Please link that library in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
app.use(vhost('account.*.*', accountApp));
app.use(vhost("www.*.*", publicApp));
```

For some reason `account.*` is not the same as `account.*.*`. So `account.*` will work on localhost. If you want to change `account.*.*` with `account.*` I recommend adding a statement that checks if you're in dev mode:

```
const isProd = proccess.env.PROD;

if(isProd) {
    app.use(vhost('account.*.*', accountApp));
    app.use(vhost("www.*.*", publicApp));
} else {
   app.use(vhost('account.*', accountApp));
   app.use(publicApp); // if you don't want to add www before localhost
}
```

Don't forget to set up subdomains in heroku and google domains, and don't forget to add env variable in heroku